# How do I update a cell from script, when the cell has a data validation rule as listbox with two objects?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have defined a data validation rule that implements a listbox in cell F4 in a sheet. The listbox is built with two objects, A and B. Only those objects are allowed. So I can choose either A or B, nothing else is allowed.

Now I would like to update the value in cell F4 from a script, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I have tried to update the cell in the same way as I update any other cell in a sheet, i.e. SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F4').setvalue('A'). This does not work. If the cell holds the value 'B' before I run the the script, nothing is changed. The statement works if I try to do this on a neighbour cell, e.g F3, without any datavalidation rule.

```
function test() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange('F4').setValue('A');
} // END function test
```

Comment: setValue () and setValues() both work for me.

Comment: Here's my code `function updateValue(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue('A')
  sh.getRange('A2:A10').setValues([['A'],['A'],['A'],['A'],['A'],['A'],['A'],['A'],['A']]);
}`

Comment: I moved the data validation to another cell on the sheet, and then everything worked as expected. Moved back to F4 again, and everything continued to work. Weird...

Comment: Can't explain that.  Well, looks like you solved the problem.